When dealing with a space like $AdS_5$, why can we take the universal cover?
In the context of the AdS/CFT correspondance, when considering $AdS_5$ we can pick the coordinates
$$x_0=R\:cosh(\rho)\: cos(\tau)
\\ x_5=R\:cosh(\rho)\:sin(\tau)
\\ x_i=R\:sinh(\rho)\:\hat{x}_i,\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\sum_{i=1}^{4}\hat{x}_i^2=1$$
Where the metric reads
$$ds^2=R^2(-cosh^2(\rho)\:d\tau^2+d\rho^2+sinh^2(\rho)\:d\Omega_3)$$
where $\Omega_3$ is the line element of a three sphere and $\tau\in [0,2\pi]$.
One can notice that time is periodic, meaning we have closed time-like curves. Closed time-like curves break causality. The standard procedure is to take the unviersal cover and "unwind" the time axis, where $\tau\in\mathbb{R}$.
Why can we do this? I understand we can change coordinates and parameters as long as the physics stays the same but by taking the unviversal cover we alter a physical aspect of the theory, the breaking of causality.

AdS5 IS the universal cover. That's the definition.
